# WCF Time Out Issue

Tags: c#, wcf

We have an application that sends an Object, in this case "printJob", to a Service.  Depending on the amount of transactions we have, this process could take awhile.  Once the Service does what it does, it returns a "PrintJobID" to the application.

```
PrintGatewayClient printClient = new PrintGatewayClient();
PrintService.ServiceJob printJob = new PrintService.ServiceJob();
printJob.ServicePrintItems = checkList.ToArray();

try
{
    currentBatch.PrintJobID = printClient.SubmitPrintJob(printJob);
    PaymentBatchesGateway.Update(currentBatch);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

printClient.Close();
```

The appliation waits and waits for the printClient to finish it's job and receive the integer of "PrintJobID" then updates a table with that ID.  However, when large batches are ran, we get the following error:

```
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:04:59.9062464. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

I have looked at our web.config file at the netTcpBinding:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IPrintGateway" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="02:00:00" sendTimeout="02:00:00"
       transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered"
       transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
       hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
       maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="50000000" maxConnections="10"
       maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000">

    <readerQuotas maxDepth="5000" maxStringContentLength="150000"
       maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="50000000" 
       maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
    <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
    </security>
    </binding>
<netTcpBinding>

<client>
    <endpoint address="http://server/printgateway/PrintGateway.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPrintGateway"
        contract="PrintService.IPrintGateway" 
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IPrintGateway" />    
</client>
```

I could not find a time out of 00:05:00 any where in the code.  Can anyone please explain and tell me how to extend this time out.  Can I do this in the code, in the web.config, on the server?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable on WCF, and I don't know where that 5 minute timeout is coming from. However for testing, have you attempted to increase the closeTimeout, openTimeout, receiveTimeout, and sendTimeout values in your <binding> to something much higher, and seeing if the expception still occurs?  I also believe you could  create an appropriate binding object, set the binding.SendTimeout =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60); (as well as the other timeout values) within the code, and use that object when you create your Service Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a thread block on a service call waiting for a response for even 60 seconds is excessive and represents poor design choices. You certainly don't want to increase this to 5 minutes, and if 5 minutes, why not an hour? This is not a realistic or supportable solution.

You would be far better off using asynchronous service calls instead.

When you go to add the service reference to the project, in the Add Service Reference dialog, click Advanced and under Client select "Generate asynchronous operations." The proxy classes generated from this will have [OperationName]Completed events and and [OperationName]Async methods for each OperationName in the service contract.

```
  var client = new Service1Client();
  client.GetDataCompleted += Client_GetDataCompleted; // specify the callback method
  client.GetDataAsync( 0 );
  // ...


static void Client_GetDataCompleted( object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e )
{
  var response = e.Result;
  // ...
}
```

The callback method is scheduled on a thread once the response message has been received by the WCF infrastructure. More at "How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx.

Comment: Unfortunately, I inherited the application from another Developer who left the company. I'm just support for the app. Can you explain what you mean by "asynchronous service calls?"

Comment: Wcf doesn't block because a single instance is serving a client for an excessive amount of time. Default behaviour would be to spawn another instance to serve a new request. But that being said async services might be a good idea, it just won't solve the timeout issue since the server still needs to do its work so it is probably a better idea to solve the performance issues. Raising the timeout would also be ok if the server handles large data transfers or similar tasks expected to be long running.

Comment: @faester, you're correct that instance-per-call is the default instancing model in WCF for services. The code shown here is client code. It is the client that is going to block, not the service. Certain service operations, like business process operations, can reasonably take a very long time (hours, weeks) to complete and return a response message. The client chooses to call the service synchronously (thread blocks waiting for the response) or asynchronously (thread does not block waiting for the response).

Comment: @Turp, I have updated the answer with information for getting started with making asynchronous service calls.

Comment: @Visual Stuart: sorry you are absolutely right that clients should be async if anything takes longer than a few ms.

Answer (score 1):

There are two config files, one at the service end and one at the consumer end. It looks like you have the consumer config. You will probably find the 5 minute timeout set in the service conifg.

However, I agree with Visual Stuart that long waits on synchronous service calls are not desirable. What should happen is that print jobs are added to a queue and after they are processed a response can be sent to the calling consumer.

However this would represent significant redevelopment effort.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation for a Silverlight control initiating business logic, which depending on what operations were choosen, would cause a timeout. I implemented a polling scenario such as below

1. WCF service method called with StartOperation which returned a unique ID to the consumer.
2. The service method kicks off a background process which does the work and simply reports a status.
3. Consumer calls a seperate wcf service status method with the unique ID to get the status.
4. Status method checks the background process (I used a singleton manager which had the running processes in a lookup dictionary) and returns its status.
5. Consumer calls #3 until done is reported.
6. The singleton manager can clean up the process after it reports done and/or allow the consumer to report its done and have it cleaned up as well.